# Is this subset sum NP complete?

Tags: ds.algorithms, subset-sum

In $\mathsf{NP}$ complete subset sum problem we ask 'Given $n$ numbers in $\Bbb Z$ is there a subset that sums to $0$?'.

Is problem 'Given $n$ of degree at most $d$ polynomials in $\Bbb Z[x]$ with coefficients in $\{0,1\}$ is there a subset of them that sums to $x^{d-1}+x^{d-2}+\dots+1$?' $\mathsf{NP}$ complete?

Is there a nice algorithm if each polynomial has exactly fixed $c\geq2$ terms or is it still $\mathsf{NP}$ complete?

Comment: If I'm understanding right, you want to select polynomials, such that for every degree $i$, exactly one of your polynomials has coefficient $1$ for the variable of degree $i$.  If so, this appears to be the exact cover problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover

Comment: @samM could you provide the reduction please?

Comment: @samM Is this association right? $X=\{x^0,x^1,\dots,x^{d-1},x^d\}$ and $\mathcal S$ is set of $n$ polynomials. We look for $\mathcal S^*\subseteq\mathcal S$ such that for each $x^i\in X$ there is an unique $p(x)\in S^*$ for which $x^i$ is a term and there is no other $q(x)\in S^*$ for which $x^i$ is a term.